# Error in simulation of a DC/DC buck converter using LTspice

Tags: dc-dc-converter, power-electronics, ltspice, buck

I am using LTspice to simulate a buck converter, but I am not getting the expected output voltage and I don't understand why.

The specification is simple: I need to get an output voltage which is half of the input one. This is the circuit I am using in the simulation:

[image]

I am using a 100kHz PWM, with a duty rate of 50%, and the value of the inductance was chosen using the lower bound to keep the circuit in CCM (using the formula L > D.(Vin-Vout)/(f.0,2.i), where D is the duty ratio, f is the frequency and I am supposing a 20% oscillation in the load current i).

The result that I obtain from the simulation is:

[image]

I don't get the 6.5V that are expected at the output. Is there any conceptual mistake here?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If all you want is to simulate, then a behavioural approach might be more handy than using real curcuit elements, such as a MOS (which, as I see, and as the other answers say, you have trouble setting it right). Instead, you can use the voltage controlled switch.

The control voltage you're using for that MOS is using a zero rise/fall time, which can't be physically true (no instant rise/fall in nature), so LTspice sets it, by default, to 10% of the `Ton`. In this case, for Ton=5\$\mu\$s, Trise=Tfall=1\$\mu\$s, which not only gives you an awful transition time, but also extends the value of Ton, from 50% Trise to 50% Tfall, to Ton+(Trise+Tfall)/2=6\$\mu\$s.

Your other values, for LC filter, for example, are awfully chosen: 1H and 10nF? How did you calculate those? I'll skip the load, maybe you intended to see the open load output? Somehow I doubt it.

If you're using the default diode, it would help setting its parameters `epsilon` and `revelsilon`, which control the knee-region to be a simple quadratic approximation, thus avoiding the sharp transitions that can cause the solver to yield `timestep too small` errors due to the possible discontinuity that results in a sharp derivative around that point. Or, you can keep things simple and use the default, quasi-real model by simply setting `.model d d Cjo=1p`, which only adds a capacitance to the junction in order to improve comvergence, while discarding the ideal model.

Also, using `startup` and `uic`, both, is not redundant, but not recommended, either (unless there are strict specifications, are there?). In your case, you're starting a switching application, so neither are needed.

Here's a reworked version of what you need, with some recalculated values for a 6.5V@1A output:

[image: buck]

I fully agree with @Dave Tweed, too often people rush to blame the tool rather than the user.

---

Here's what a quasi-real setup would be:

[image: pmos]

Note the PMOS (usually when in high side), driven by a signal that's between `GND` and `13V` (or close, some losses simulated) -- as the other answers have suggested --, and some parasitics. Instead of `V2` there's usually some sort of control, voltage- or current-mode, that's  a different question, but one that you should be able to find already answered.

Comment: Thank you! But how do I go from this behavioural approach to a real circuit using an NMOS transistor? Are there other subcircuits that need to be designed in order to get this result using a circuit replacing the switch with a transistor?

Comment: @ViníciusLopesSimões See the updated answer. Note that the parts used here are in no way representative to a real design -- that's up to you to determine.  I merely used them as a reference.

Answer (score 4):

Yes. You are using a N-channel MOSFET as your switching element, and driving it with a signal that only goes to +5V.

The MOSFET is operating as a source-follower when it is on, and the output voltage can only rise as far as Vg - Vth, which in this case is only about 1.6 V

Either use a P-channel MOSFET, driven with a gate signal that is negative with respect to its source voltage (the supply voltage), or use a proper N-channel MOSFET driver that can drive the gate *above* the input voltage.

Note that if you had simply plotted the voltage across the diode, this would have been pretty obvious. I can never understand why people use simulators, and then don't take advantage of all the information they have to offer...

Comment: +1 for the rant about people not taking advantage of the simulation tools.

Answer (score 4):

On top of what Dave said, instead of using generic models, try assigning a real MOS and a real diode by right clicking on each component and then on "Pick New MOSFET" and "Pick New Diode". This might allow you to obtain a better result. You still won't get the result you expect because of the losses. You will probably need to modify the duty cycle a little bit.

Answer (score 3):

I suspect you don’t know the rule of thumb that  Vgs must be greater than 2.5 x Vt to get a reasonable RdsOn.

It may be more for 2~4V threshold devices and less for  Vt<1V. Where   Vt == gs(th). Worst case